# Enable only one settings page open in chome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I chrome extention in my `popup.html` I have a "settings" button, for now when I click this button it opens the settings page in a new tab, and it's possible to open multiple pages, my question is how to prevent multiple settings instances, i.e I want to enable only **one** settings page open.

My code:

```
<button type="button">
     <a id="settings-btn"> <i class="fa fa-cog  fa-lg fa-fw" style="font-size:27px;"></i></a>
</button>
```

And in `popup.js`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("settings-btn").addEventListener("click", openIndex);
})

function openIndex() {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "Options.html"
    });
}
```

---

**Update:**

@wOxxOm's answer worked after I added `tabs` permission in manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods.

1. **Using `tabs` permission and [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) to find the existing tab**

   manifest.json:

   ```js
   "permissions": ["tabs"]
   ```

   popup.js

   ```js
   openOrActivate('Options.html');

   function openOrActivate(url) {
     if (!url.includes(':')) url = chrome.runtime.getURL(url);
     chrome.tabs.query({url: url + '*'}, tabs => {
       const [tab] = tabs;
       if (!tab) {
         chrome.tabs.create({url});
       } else {
         chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {active: true});
         chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {focused: true});
       }
     });
   }
   ```
2. **Send a message that will be received by an options page if it's open**

   In case of no response we'll open a new tab.

   popup.js:

   ```js
   openOrActivate('Options.html');

   function openOrActivate(path) {
     if (!path.startsWith('/')) path = `/${path}`;
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage(path, tab => {
       if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !tab) {
         chrome.tabs.create({ url: path });
       } else {
         chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
         chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true });
       }
     });
   }
   ```

   Options.js (the script of Options.html):

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
     if (message === location.pathname) {
       chrome.tabs.getCurrent(sendResponse);
       return true;
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: It works now, I was needed to add `tabs` permission

Comment: I've added a second method that doesn't require `tabs` permission.